# Rails: validate uniqueness of two columns (together)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `Release` model with `medium` and `country` columns (among others). There should not be `releases` that share identical `medium`/`country` combinations.

How would I write this as a rails validation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Validate uniqueness of multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 349, accepted):

You can use a [uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validation with the `scope` option.

Also, you should add a unique index to the DB to prevent new records from passing the validations when checked at the same time before being written:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToReleases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :releases, [:country, :medium], unique: true
  end
end



class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :country, uniqueness: { scope: :medium }
end
```

Comment: +1 for the index, but -1 for the `unique` as it is not recognized. For that part I have used the answer below.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the validation key should be `uniqueness`, not `unique`. See the linked documentation. Fixing the answer.

Comment: Hm, nice, thanks :) To repeat myself - putting the index brings the solution to the next level, and not just like other "coding" solutions that I have been running into, before finding this answer. +1 for that

Comment: 'Pass' an array to `scope:` to check uniqueness across more than two fields.

Comment: Would this work if we had a partial unique index? Lets say we define the unique index with "If medium is not null". We would have many pairs with "country" null. Are these treated as unique or not unique? To answer my own question: If you add allow_nil: true to validates as answered here it will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496223/possible-to-specify-unique-index-with-nulls-allowed-in-rails-activerecord

Answer (score 134):

All the above answers are missing how to validate the uniqueness of multiple attributes in a model. The code below intends to tell how to use multiple attributes in a scope.

```
validates :country, uniqueness: { scope: [:medium, :another_medium] }
```

It validates uniqueness of `country` in all rows with values of `medium` and `another_medium`.

**Note:** Don't forget to add an index on the above column, this insures fast retrieval and adds a DB level validation for unique records.

**Update:** For adding an index while creating table

```
t.index [:country, :medium, :another_medium], unique: true
```

Comment: since the validates is based on 3 column the index table should too
t.index [:country, :medium, :another_medium], unique: true

Comment: Your `t.index` taught me something.  I thought Rails couldn't do multicolumn indexes.

Answer (score 53):

You can pass a `:scope` parameter to your validator like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :medium, scope: :country
```

See the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) for some more examples.

Comment: @DennisBest It "works", but it doesn't protect against race conditions. If two clients make simultaneous requests, they could both pass validation if neither is committed to the database before the other is validated. You also need a database unique constraint as in tompave's answer.