# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"ation: ERROR: du

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I used omniauth-kakao gem to login through SNS.

Then I succeed to login and I got token and profile of SNS.

But when the other user(not me) has signed up through SNS, I met the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
```

And this is code in `app/model/user.rb` that makes the error

```
def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
  identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)
  user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

  if user.nil?
    email = auth.info.email
    user = User.where(:email => email).first
    unless self.where(email: auth.info.email).exists?
      if user.nil?
          user = User.new(
            profile_img: auth.info.image,
            password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
          )
        user.save!      #Error message said this line is problem
      end
    end
  end

  if identity.user != user
    identity.user = user
    identity.save!
  end
  user
end
```

Also, I made two model. `User.rb` and `Identity.rb`.(Identity.rb refer User.rb)

`Identity.rb` has 'Provider(sns)', 'User' column. 
`User.rb` has user's information, profile of SNS column.

When error occur, row was added to `Identity.rb` and this row has not user_id in 'User' column.(Others was added, only user_id was not added)

In addition, row was not added to `User.rb` never

What's the problem??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496223/possible-to-specify-unique-index-with-nulls-allowed-in-rails-activerecord

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be saving `email` with user in db in below code:

```
if user.nil?

    user = User.new(
      profile_img: auth.info.image,

      password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    )
  user.save!      #Error message said this line is problem
end
```

It should be like:

```
if user.nil?

    user = User.new(
      profile_img: auth.info.image,
      email: email,
      password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    )
  user.save!      #Error message said this line is problem
end
```